# How to perform correct manipulation of child?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, mindmaps

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=black!10, 
    level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45},]
\node{Lorem}
   child [concept color=cyan!40] { node {Ipsum}
        child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
            child { node {sit}}
               }
        child { node {amet} 
            child { node {consectetur}}
            child { node {adipiscing}}
            child { node {elit}}
        }
        child { node {Aliquam}
            child { node {tincidunt}}
            child { node {interdum}}
            child { node {faucibus}}
               }
        child [style={sibling angle=50}] { node {Curabitur}
            child{ node {id}}
               }
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!50] { node {malesuada}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
    }
    child [concept color=red!40] { node {adipiscing}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
    }
    child [concept color=green!50] { node {elit}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Result (focused on the important):

[image: Result focused on the important]

## Explanation and questions:

The concept map in the MWE was made based on a template that is very popular around here. As you may see there are some issues and things that should be manageable.

- The main one and more noticeable in the picture is the big node,  the "strings" attaching to it are really short compared to the node which makes it ugly.
- The colors of the strings when the child changes color with respect to its parent are slightly different (to be honest not so "slightly" more like much different).

Now, having said so, the questions are:

- Where can one get a complete (or full) set of commands like `concept color` when dealing with concept maps with Tikz? Commands that allow you to perform changes in the node or in the child.
- How can be the child move varying it's distance from the parent? Without affecting the level's distance from child to parent.
- Refer to the child painted in green in the picture: I tried moving this child angularly (varying it's angle) `child [style={sibling angle=50}]`, but the angle is not relative to the position where the child is originally placed (instead it seems to be relative to the parent position), and the angles are not normally scaled (a turn is about 210 degrees instead of 360 degrees). What is the correct way of position a child relatively to its "original" position? (Without affecting the angle positioning in the level).
- Can the color of the "strings" between the child of different colors be fixed to make them look better?

Comment: The site works best when you ask one question per... well, per question, really. If the questions are linked, you can include links in your later questions so people can get relevant context or background if that might be helpful. The answer to question (1) is that `mindmap`s are covered in the PGF/TikZ manual where there is a section for this library and, earlier, quite an extensive tutorial-type example. I don't understand the second question. The level distance just is the distance from parent to child, isn't it?

Comment: @crf I believe I'll let your advise for next time (unless you want me to edit my question and create more questions to answer the questions I placed here). And, all right, I'll search for that in the manual then. The second question, well yes, I just found that out. I better read the Tikz manual right away.

Comment: Lovely title btw.

Comment: @JPi Haha, I know, I should have started like "Now that I have your attention", but they'll say it's spam or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the commands, see the TikZ manual which covers the library and includes an extensive tutorial on this topic.

To move a single node, you can set `level distance` for that node. But since the level distance just *is* the distance between parent and child, you cannot alter the latter without changing the former.

The colour problem is caused by the fact that you are getting *different* cyans using different colour models. The result is that they do not match. To fix this, you can use the `rgb` option for `xcolor` *before* loading `tikz`.

For example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
  [
    mindmap,
    grow cyclic,
    every node/.style=concept,
    concept color=black!10,
    level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm, sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm, sibling angle=45},
    root concept/.append style={concept, concept color=black!10},
  ]
  node [root concept] {Lorem}
   child [concept color=cyan!40] { node {Ipsum}
        child [level distance=40mm] { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
            child [level distance=35mm] { node {sit}}
               }
        child { node {amet}
            child { node {consectetur}}
            child { node {adipiscing}}
            child { node {elit}}
        }
        child { node {Aliquam}
            child { node {tincidunt}}
            child { node {interdum}}
            child { node {faucibus}}
               }
        child [style={sibling angle=50}] { node {Curabitur}
            child{ node {id}}
               }
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!50] { node {malesuada}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
    }
    child [concept color=red!40] { node {adipiscing}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
    }
    child [concept color=green!50] { node {elit}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
        child { node {}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted mind map]

You can use `grow` or `rotate` etc. to alter angles. Which makes most sense depends on the particular case: the manual has all the gory details.